# How do I count the number of non-zeros in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a macro that will go through a whole workbook and count the number of days a employee worked. The sheets have the work broken out in days so all T have to find is the days that are not zero. I have tried to use `COUNTIF(A11:A12,">0")` and I get the error `Expected : list separator or )`. I am using a `For Each` loop to work through the sheets. I would like to put all the information on a new sheet at the end of the workbook with the name of the employee and the days worked. I am very new to visual basic but am quite good with c#.

I now have gotten this far

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetLoop2()
    ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
    Dim Current As Worksheet
    Dim LastColumn As Integer

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
    ' Search for any entry, by searching backwards by Columns.
        LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    End If

    ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
    For Each Current In Worksheets
        Current.Range("A27") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Current.Range(Cells(11, LastColumn), Cells(16, LastColumn)), ">0")
        Current.Range("A28") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Current.Range("Al17:Al22"), ">0")
    Next
End Sub
```

When I run this I get an error saying `method range of object'_worksheet' failed`. I also haven't been able to find a way to get the information all on the summary sheet.

Comment: If you need VBA, place `Application.WorksheetFunction.` in front of CountIf. If you don't want VBA, it is possible to derive a solution with just formulas.

Comment: taking what Scott suggested, 1 step forward.. use this `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A11:A12"), ">0")`

Comment: I am using this and it doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't put the number count in a27 like it should
`Sub WorksheetLoop2()

   ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
   Dim Current As Worksheet
    
    
   ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
   For Each Current In Worksheets
        
        
    A27 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A11:A12"), ">0")


   Next

End Sub'

Comment: see edits to my answer below, based on this commented you last posted

Answer (score 1):

VBA Solution, in light of your last comment above.

Good VBA programming practice entails always using Option Explicit with your code, that way you know when you don't have variables declared correctly, or, sometimes, if code is bad! In this case you would have picked up that just writing A27 does not mean you are returning the value to cell A27, but rather just setting the value you get to variable A27.  Or maybe you wouldn't know that exactly, but you would find out where your problem is real quick!

This code should fix it for you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetLoop2()

'Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
Dim Current As Worksheet

' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each Current In Worksheets
    Current.Range("A27") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Current.Range("A11:A12"), ">0")
Next

End Sub
```

In case it helps, Non-VBA solution:

Assuming you have a Summary sheet and each employee on a separate sheet, with days in column A and hours worked in column B, enter formula in formula bar in B1 of Summary and run down the list of names in column A.

[image: Sheet]

Comment: if i had the name in a cell on each sheet. How would I put the name and the days worked on the a summary sheet. thanks for all the help

Comment: Well, the basic formula is `=mySheet1!A1` where `mySheet` is the Sheet Name and `A1` is the cell reference. YOu can also use indirect, like I did above, and say, type mySheet in cell A1 and type `= Indirect(A1 & "!A1")` in B1 to get the name.